# Delete Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Is there a possibility to return to normal Google Analytics Tracking code Snippet, deleting Google Tag Manager Code Snippet?

I tried to install Google Tag Manager and put the code snippet below the body tag.

Then I deleted the Google Analytics Code Snippet and after one day all the data in Google Analytics was gone. Because of that, I decided I will track my pages without Google Tag Manager and deleted Google Tag Manager Code Snippet from all of my pages and put again Google Analytics Code Snippet, but there are still no results. The interesting thing is that when I go to Admin to check the status of Tracking, it shows it is active.

I am not sure where is the problem, if nothing is working, can I create new Google Analytics account with the same website and start all the process again?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you mention that sound suspicious:

1. when you remove the GA tracking code, data doesn't just get deleted. You would likely know you are deleting data if you actually tried to; it won't happen suddenly without your knowledge or consent (unless you are not the only administrator). Check that you are logged into the correct account, too.
2. When you say there are no results after you put the GA tracking code back in, are you checking right away in your standard reports?

You can definitely replace the GTM snippet with the GA snippet (putting it in the correct place in the  tags), but you should probably debug the issue first. Keep in mind that when you put the GA snippet back on your pages, I believe you would need to wait around 24 hours for data to be processed into your standard reports, but in the meantime, you can check in Real-Time reports to see if you are getting any hits. You also can create a new GA account, but, again, I would try debugging your original implementation because you could see the same thing happen with a new account.

Comment: Thank you!!! It was a bug, you were right! I removed the codes from every page of my site that I want to track and then put it again, but the basic one from GA. I also found the bug, installing this extensions from Google Chrome (Tag Assistent and Google Analytics Debug), which are very helpful! More information could be found on the following page: http://www.optimizesmart.com/geek-guide-google-analytics-debugging-troubleshooting/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Simply using the basic analytics code will revert back. you will not loose any historical data, as it doesn't work like that. you will simply just stop reporting anything custom, and report only basic. And like I said, all you have to do, is remove the code for GTM, and add the code for GA.